# Sencha Touch 2 - How to get form values?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've got a Sencha Touch 2 MVC app with a form as a view.
I'm trying to get it's values from the controller with no success.

How could this be done? I'm posting my view/controller code for this one.

View:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Login',
                id: 'loginform',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'emailfield',
                        name: 'email',
                        label: 'Email'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name: 'password',
                        label: 'Password'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                width: '50%',
                text: 'Login',
                ui: 'confirm',
                id: 'btnSubmitLogin'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'MyApp Mobile'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

And the controller:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.LoginForm", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    config: {
        refs: {
            btnSubmitLogin: "#btnSubmitLogin"
        },
        control: {
            btnSubmitLogin: {
                tap: "onSubmitLogin"
            }
        }
    },
    onSubmitLogin: function () {
        console.log("onSubmitLogin");
        var values = app.views.LoginForm.loginform.getValues();
        TryLogin(values['email'], values['password']);
    },
    launch: function () {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm launch");
    },
    init: function () {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm init");
    }
});
```

The code will go up to

```
console.log("onSubmitLogin");
```

And then stop.

On launch I use this:

```
var LoginForm = Ext.create("MyApp.view.LoginForm");
Ext.Viewport.add(LoginForm);
```

So, how can I get the values?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok. Found the answer after some tweaking. For the sake of future generations - here is the solution:

I've added `id:'loginform'` to the LoginForm and then, in the controller in the 'refs' part I've added `loginForm: '#loginform'`.
Then I could use it as :

```
var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
```

Good luck to all

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution to this! It helped me out greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Controller:

```
    Ext.define("mySIMS.controller.LoginForm", {
        extend : "Ext.app.Controller",
        config : {
            refs : {
                btnSubmitLogin : "#btnSubmitLogin",
                LoginForm : '#loginform'
            },
            control : {
                btnSubmitLogin : {
                    tap : "onSubmitLogin"
                }
            }
        },
        onSubmitLogin : function() {
            console.log("onSubmitLogin");
            var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
            console.log(values);

            //var values = Oreilly.views.LoginForm.loginform.getValues();

        },
        launch : function() {
            this.callParent();
            console.log("LoginForm launch");
        },
        init : function() {
            this.callParent();
            console.log("LoginForm init");
        }
    });
```

View:

```
    Ext.define('mySIMS.view.LoginForm', {
        extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
        config : {
            id : 'loginform',
            fullscreen : true,
            items : [{
                xtype : 'fieldset',
                title : 'Login',
                items : [{
                    xtype : 'emailfield',
                    name : 'email',
                    label : 'Email'
                }, {
                    xtype : 'passwordfield',
                    name : 'password',
                    label : 'Password'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype : 'button',
                width : '8%',
                text : 'Login',
                ui : 'confirm',
                id : 'btnSubmitLogin'
            }, {
                xtype : 'toolbar',
                docked : 'top',
                title : 'Mobile'
            }]
        }
    });
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Please be more descriptive about your solution. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)